# Well, it's been a year

Tags: discussion, stats

...and 1 day.

Joomla Stack Exchange has come quite far and is getting much more popular.

#### Questions per day

There was a period where we were on 11 per day, which I was hoping would continue to stay as is, or increase, but unfortunately it didn't. A lot of people are still asking their question on Stackoverflow. I've tried to get a fair amount of people to post on JSE and even requested a migrations on some, but I think people are still unaware of JSE.

#### Answered Questions

The percentage has slowly decreased as time has progressed. Every once in a while it would be good if a few of us could do a small skim through and either come up with a possible answer (or pointer in the right direction), or close it if too broad.

#### Total users

The 2k and 3k marks have already been complete, so I think it's just the popularity that's preventing us from getting 150 users with 20+ rep. This will simply improve in due time.

#### Answer ratio

Bit of a tricky one in my opinion. I've seen a lot of answers that have been upvoted and accepted soon after the question was posted. Which is perfectly fine, but it doesn't always mean it's the *best* solution. My advice would simply be, if you see this, don't be afraid to post another answer, even if it, expands a little on what the other user has posted.

#### Daily visitors

Over the last couple of months, we've had a steady/stable amount of daily visitors which is good.

---

Overall, big thanks to everyone for dedicating their time to help JSE progress :)

See results below:

[image]

Comment: It's really pretty cool to see how Joomla.StackExchange.com has grown and continues to thrive - and thanks for posting the stats!  As per your suggestion to just add another answer, I would also consider, where appropriate, to edit the existing answer(s) - so that rather than get a bunch of 'mediocre' or incomplete answers, we have one or two great answers which rise to the top.